# How to execute cell 1 from another notebook in current notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I have a bunch of notebooks in a directory dir1 and would like to write a master notebook that executes the first cell of each notebook in dir1. All notebooks in dir1 have markdown describing themselves in cell 1. So by executing the first cell of all of them, the master notebook will document all notebooks in dir1. This sounds easily doable but I don't have any idea how to proceed.

A more general question is, is there software that will extract the markdown in cell 1 of all notebooks in dir1 and create a nice master notebook from them? nbsphinx produces an html doc, but I would like something much more lightweight and quicker.

Comment: If the cells you want to extract are just markdown, you don't need to run the notebook. Notebooks are just JSON files. In a script, or in the master notebook, you can open each file, get the first cell and save a new notebook, let's say `summary.ipynb`, where you collect all the first cells.

Comment: Okay, I can use os.listdir() to get the files and I can use json to load the files, and access the first cells. So I think I am capable of creating a list of the strings which are in the first cells. I can then create a giant string concatenating all the substrings. How do I open a new notebook and put the giant string into a cell?

Comment: Okay,  I haven't coded it yet, but I think I can do everything in the current notebook. No need to create a new notebook. Once I get my giant string, I can just say display(Markdown(giant_string)) Hopefull

Comment: Hopefully, display(Markdown()) can interpret the superset of markdown  that jupyter markdown cells use. Don't know yet

Comment: Coded it. Works beautifully. As per my last plan, I don't create a new notebook, I just assemble my giant string and use display(Markdown(giant_string))

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code that I used. I create a notebook called `SUMMARY.ipynb` inside dir1 and I put this code into a cell of SUMMARY.ipynb. Running this cell produces a nice summary of all the notebooks in dir1 with a link to them

```
import os
import json
from IPython.display import display, Markdown

# the name of this file
this_fname = 'SUMMARY.ipynb'
fname_to_md = {}
for fname in os.listdir('./'):
    if fname[-6:] == '.ipynb'  and fname != this_fname:
        # print('------------', fname)
        with open(fname, 'r', encoding="utf-8") as f:
            fdata = json.load(f)
            fname_to_md[fname] = ''.join(fdata['cells'][0]['source'])
            # print(fname_to_md)
pre_sep = '\n\n<span style="color:red">%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%</span>\n\n'
full_md = ''
for fname, md in fname_to_md.items():
    sep = pre_sep
    sep += '[<a href="' + fname + '" target= "_blank">' + fname + '</a>]\n\n'
    full_md += sep + md
display(Markdown(full_md))
```